# How to click on a <span> button inside a website using VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, dom, getelementbyid

so I want to click on a button in a website. I tried using the **GetElementById** but the button has **no ID** and it has those span things that confuse me. It also has no href so I guess its not a link or something nor it has a "a" tag or what do they call that (very sorry i do not know how to code well yet).
Here is the button's **HTML** code :

`<span class="now-click" style="display: none;">Click</span>`

I tried those but didn't help : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038131/getelement-by-class-name-for-clicking) and
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242823/clicking-a-html-element-in-vb-net-webbrowser)

Do you know how could I make a button in my Windows Form Application press on this button with InvokeMember("click")?

Comment: *Windows Form Application*? Do you mean webforms?

Comment: I am using vb.net Windows Form Application in Visual Studio 2015, i have a webbrowser and a button. I want the button to click on the "Click" button displayed in my webbrowser.

Comment: hope made it clear enough ._.

Comment: what is that? do i have to install something or what?

Comment: have you tried to iterate by tag name and then filter by inner text? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480731/webbrowser-click-button-with-no-id-or-name and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442882/finding-and-clicking-a-button-with-no-id-within-html-code-in-webbrowser

Comment: both of the links use TagNames, in my case there are no tags

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing element name with tag name. In you example, span is the tag name and there's no element name. There are tags in HTML... just google for html tag names

Comment: Oh now i get it. I tried it with span , did not work. but the cursor seemed like it was loading and the button did not get clicked. I even tried removing the InnerText part and still nothing. But why?

Answer (score 0):

What you need might is the following 3 lines of code:

```
var span = document.querySelector("span.now-click");
var click = new Event('click');
span.dispatchEvent(click);
```

What is essentially happening here is that we are fetching the span from the DOM, and after that creating a click event. Subsequently, we are dispatching the aforesaid event on the eventTarget which is the `span` in this case.

Here I have made a little demo to give you a clearer understanding of the same. When the 'Tester' button is clicked, is calls a function which runs the above 3 lines of code. Also I have added an EventListener to the span which causes an alert saying 'Span was clicked' whenever the span is clicked. Hope this makes it clear. You can see that clicking the span or the button have the same affect, i.e. clicking the span.

```js
function clickSpan() {
  var span= document.querySelector("span.now-click");
  var click= new Event('click');
  span.dispatchEvent(click);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickSpan()">Tester</button>
<span class="now-click" onclick="alert('Span was clicked.')">This is span.</span>
```

Comment: under the Private Sub Button1_Click i paste the codes that you provided? I am new sorry if i'm trouble

Comment: i want to do that in VB.NET Windows Form Application with a button and a webbrowser.

Comment: I don't really know VB.NET sorry.